# PHP container build in docker fails with error

Tags: php, postgresql, docker, makefile, docker-compose

I am writing a small pet project and using docker

I am using PHP-CLI, PHP-FPM and PGSQL - apline.

Below is the configuration

php-cli Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0-cli-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache autoconf g++ make

#install PG
RUN apk add --no-cache postgresql-dev bash coreutils \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql

RUN apk add --no-cache unzip
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql pcntl opcache
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath fileinfo

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/bin --filename=composer --quiet

WORKDIR /app
```

PHP-fpm dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm-alpine

#install PG
RUN apk add --no-cache postgresql-dev bash coreutils \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql

#enable extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql opcache bcmath fileinfo

WORKDIR /app
```

docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: seln_nginx_dev-container
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./:/app
    links:
      - php-fpm
    ports:
      - '8000:80'

  php-fpm:
    container_name: seln_php-fpm-container
    build:
      context: docker
      dockerfile: php-fpm/Dockerfile
    environment:
      DB_HOST: api-postgres
      DB_USER: app
      DB_PASSWORD: secret
      DB_NAME: app
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    working_dir: /app

  php-cli:
    container_name: seln_php-cli-container
    build:
      context: docker
      dockerfile: php-cli/Dockerfile
    environment:
      DB_HOST: api-postgres
      DB_USER: app
      DB_PASSWORD: secret
      DB_NAME: app
    volumes:
      - ./:/app

  api-postgres:
    image: postgres:13.1-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: app
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
      POSTGRES_DB: app
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5432:5432"
```

And Makefile

```
init: down build up composer-install init-db
up:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up -d
down:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml down -v --remove-orphans
composer-install:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml run --rm php-cli composer install
composer-update:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml run --rm php-cli composer update
build:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml build
init-db:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml run --rm php-cli vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:drop --force && \
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml run --rm php-cli vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
clear-cache:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml run --rm php-cli vendor/bin/doctrine orm:clear-cache:metadata && \
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml run --rm php-cli vendor/bin/doctrine orm:clear-cache:query
```

What I am running into, when trying to build docker to work, I get an error use `make init` command

```
make: /bin/sh: Operation not permitted
make: *** [Makefile:209: pdo_pgsql.lo] Error 127
The command '/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql opcache bcmath fileinfo' returned a non-zero code: 2
ERROR: Service 'php-fpm' failed to build : Build failed
```

what is the reason for this error?

P>S - I managed to fix the error(use `FROM php:8.0-cli-alpine3.13`), but this solution does not suit me, I want to understand the reason, before the Ubuntu update, I could collect images without crutches, what could have changed in two weeks?

Comment: You did not provide enough of the output.  What was the make command you ran?  What commands were printed _before_ these error messages?  That will tell you which command failed to run.  It's possible that you need to run that command with elevated privileges (as root--within the container).

Comment: @MadScientist - I used the make init command. P>S - I managed to fix the error, but this solution does not suit me, I want to understand the reason, before the Ubuntu update, I could collect images without crutches, what could have changed in two weeks? Added data in the question

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  I wanted to know what `docker-compose` command was generating the error you wrote, the full sets of errors shown.  The error you're seeing appears to be generated from some `make` command running in your container, but you haven't shown the actual commands that were run etc.  The output you show is just the "aftermath" of the real problem.  Anyway, I'm not a docker-compose person, nor do I know anything about php etc.  But anyone who does know about these things will need to see the actual errors I expect.